# How to clean a <script> tag and extract information from specific key

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape information from a site (first experience), i was able to do the easy part of it which is extracting from "div" with the help of SOF.

However, the second part is a bit hard, the list contains one item that looks like the following :

```
[<script class="BLABLA" type="application/json">
{"language":"fr",
"wakawaka":[{"id":2,"name":"Is Xtra Natsss"},{"id":13,"name":"BLO"},{"id":14,"name":"WAK95"}],
"store":[{"id":2,"name":"Is Xtra Nanou"},{"id":13,"name":"BLO"},{"id":14,"name":"WAK95"}]}
</script>]
```

The data has been dummified, however, I am wondering how can I extract the info for "store" for example?

Many thanks.

Comment: is this a `list` containing one `string` in your example?

Comment: add your full code an a link to site, that you want to parse, the element in your example needs to be reproduced for proper handling

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy yes it is a list containing one element only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you each time get elements like in your example (as a string!), you can get `store` data as, for example, a `dict` as follows:

```
lst = ['''<script class="BLABLA" type="application/json">
{"language":"fr",
"wakawaka":[{"id":2,"name":"Is Xtra Natsss"},{"id":13,"name":"BLO"},{"id":14,"name":"WAK95"}],
"store":[{"id":2,"name":"Is Xtra Nanou"},{"id":13,"name":"BLO"},{"id":14,"name":"WAK95"}]}
</script>''']


string_for_dict = lst[0][lst[0].index('"store":[') + 9:lst[0].index('}]}') + 1]
store_dictionary = eval(string_for_dict)
```

result:

```
({'id': 2, 'name': 'Is Xtra Nanou'},
 {'id': 13, 'name': 'BLO'},
 {'id': 14, 'name': 'WAK95'})
```

What's happening:

simply cutting string by indexes where needed part begins (`"store":[`) plus 9 symbols which is the length of this string (`len('"store":[')`) and ends (`}]}`) plus one symbol to include first closing bracet to meet `dict` format for `eval`.

`eval` in it's turn parses string and returns you a `dict`.

Comment: I highly appreciate the effort, i will go through the answer in a bit.

Comment: @Dimitriy any idea how to get lat and lng from this? `long_lat_info[0].findAll("div")`
`[<div class="distance dist-loaded" lat="66.89018540" lng="9.7390062000">17.9</div>]
`

Comment: @ombk try `long_lat_info[0].findAll("div")[0]['lat']` and `long_lat_info[0].findAll("div")[0]['lng']`

Comment: yess!! and all worked ! sorry for not being responsive

Answer (score 1):

An alterative approach; if you know you have json, then just convert string to json using `json.loads`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

html = '''<script class="BLABLA" type="application/json">
{"language":"fr",
"wakawaka":[{"id":2,"name":"Is Xtra Natsss"},{"id":13,"name":"BLO"},{"id":14,"name":"WAK95"}],
"store":[{"id":2,"name":"Is Xtra Nanou"},{"id":13,"name":"BLO"},{"id":14,"name":"WAK95"}]}
</script>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script') # Using find_all to mimic data in question.
json = json.loads(scripts[0].contents[0])
for store in json['store']:
    print(store['name'])
```

Comment: I highly appreciate the effort, i will go through the answer in a bit.